# Drill cone-shaped hole

Tags: wood

I want to drill a cone-shaped hole in some thick wood. The hole needs to be about 75mm deep and 45mm diameter at the surface. The *accuracy* of the dimensions isn't so important, but I do want the *finish* to be very smooth inside the walls.

I tried drilling with hole saws and forstner bits to produce a series of "steps" to the bottom, this worked well but I'm now struggling to grind away the steps into a smooth cone.

I was thinking of using a step-drill to finish the hole - but they don't seem to make them this big - and they are very expensive.

So I'm looking for either a way to drill a cone from scratch - or a way to grind the "steps" to make the walls smooth.

I have a wide array of power tools and hand tools but no lathe or CNC machine!

Comment: A little help for those who are not familiar with mm or who need to search in inches: 45 mm is 1.77 inch or nearest standard size 1 3/4 inch.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for that. I should have allowed for Americans in my question.

Comment: This does work here, but *might* work better at Woodworking SE.

Comment: Do you have a drill press?

Comment: @Brad Yes, but not a very good one. What's your plan...?

Comment: just wondering if there is a way to cut two pieces of angle bracket, interlock them and make a four pointed "bit" that you could chuck into. it would be way stronger than a flat piece of metal.

Comment: @Brad Do you essentially mean a CROSS-shaped pyramid rather than just a triangle? That would definitely be stronger than a flat plate - and would also be easier to put into a chuck.

Answer (score 2):

A [tapered reamer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004BCWSSU) would produce a smooth finish, though I've not seen one of ~50 mm diameter.

You might make your own tool from a piece of metal. Form a cone from some sheet metal, e.g. iron or brass (not aluminum) and solder the overlap, leaving an abrupt edge along the cone. Drill or punch two diametrically-opposed holes at the wide end and slip a rod stock or cross-point screw-driver though the holes and you've made a light-duty reamer, suitable for smoothing soft woods (not hornbeam or lignum vitae, though).

Comment: I like the idea of your "conical drill-bit" - but I think even easier would be just to cut a *triangle* of the right dimensions, mount on a shaft and let the sharp edge of the metal grind the hole out to the final size - a bit like a tile drill. Still trying to work out how to centre a triangle of metal on a shaft though....?!

Comment: A triangle should also work, but if the metal is not thick, it will twist. A standard wood bit has a triangular-shaped tip, after all.

Comment: Good point. If I don't have thick enough metal, I might try bracing with some wood either side in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Grinding the steps should be easy enough. Use a round file to get rid of the steps, then sand to the finish you want. If you want a smoother finish than you can get using sanding alone, apply a few coats of varnish and sand that.

Comment: I do have a round file and haven't tried that so will give it a go and report back. I suspect it may be a little too laborious. Sanding is the problem - there's not enough room to get paper in there properly. I REALLY like the idea of the varnish though. I think it will solve a lot of problems, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

One possible soloution if you don't mind a coupld of small screwholes in the back of your panel.

Fix a peice of scrap wood to the back of your main panel.

Drill through both your panel and the scrap wood with a holesaw.

use a router to cut the angle on the edge, the scrap wood is used to guide the router.